# UISearchBar with UIPopoverController holding results cannot be interacted with while UIPopoverController is on screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipad, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller

I have a UISearchBar. When the user touches the UISearchBar, a UIPopoverController is shown that contains a UITableView of results. As the user types, the results appear.

I want the user to be able to touch the grey x button in the UISearchBar to clear the search results and clear the UISearchBar's text field. However, the first touch simply dismisses the UIPopoverController, prompting the user to touch the button a second time to clear out the text field.

Is there a way to allow touch interaction with other object while a UIPopoverController is showing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the `passthroughViews` property of the UIPopoverController to the UISearchBar.

In fact, the Apple sample app [ToolbarSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) does exactly this:

```
// Ensure the popover is not dismissed if the user taps in the search bar.
popover.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:searchBar];
```

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for, just didn't know how to go about finding it. I appreciate your help.